# Multi Step Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, phpexcel

Currently I have 2 columns in the EXCEL. PARENT_ID, GRAND_PARENT_ID.And wanted to figure out the multi level Parenting issues. For instance

```
PARENT_ID 111 rolls to GRAND_PARENT_ID 222
AND
PARENT_ID 222 rolls to GRAND_PARENT_ID 333
AND 
PARENT_ID 333 rolls to GRAND_PARENT_ID 444

Until PARENT_ID = GRAND_PARENT_ID.
```

So i need to figure out how many levels which PARENT_ID is rolling up. I have like millions of rows and tried to figure out a vlookup, but its just killing/freezing my session.

I tried vlookup GRAND_PARENT_ID to PARENT_ID and then again take the chunk that exist and again do a vlookup to the PARENT_ID.its simply freezing my session as am having millions of rows

```
PARENT_ID   GRAND_PARENT_ID
111 222
222 333
333 444
444 444
```

Expected result: `111 222 333 444 until the PARENT_ID to GRAND_PARENT_ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going from VLOOKUP to INDEX/MATCH makes almost no difference if you're only returning one value for each match and still using exact matching.

An immense gain can be made by sorting your data first and using approximate lookups instead (in either VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH).

First sort the data by ParentID ascending, then use the following formula to lookup values:

`=IF(VLOOKUP(ParentID,Data,1,TRUE)=ParentID, VLOOKUP(ParentID,Data,2,TRUE), NA())`

If you know for 100% certain that a ParentID can always be found, you could simplify to just:

`=VLOOKUP(ParentID,Data,2,TRUE)`

Again, note that you **must** sort your data by ParentID first. And you **must** exclude the column heading in the Data range.

This is faster because when doing an exact match lookup, Excel will just start at the top of the list and check every single value until it finds an exact match. So for a list with 1 million rows, that requires up to 1 millions comparisons.

For an approximate match on sorted data, Excel instead does a binary search. It checks the middle number, then goes higher or lower and checks the next middle number again and so on. In a list with 1 million rows, it takes a maximum of 20 comparisons to narrow down to a single value, making it run up to 50,000 times faster.

https://exceljet.net/formula/faster-vlookup-with-2-vlookups

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUPS` are very processor consuming for Excel, you would be better off switching to the more complicated (but lighter) `INDEX MATCH` method which is explained in detail here: https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

If it is an option you should also check and see if you are using 32 or 64 bit Excel. (File --> Help --> Right side of screen). If your computer is a 64 bit processor then switching from 32 bit Excel to 64 bit Excel may give you a small performance boost as Excel will utilize more of your computers processing power.